# Adding text to textarea in the presence of many form submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to fetch some string from the server. For that purpose, I am using the `ajax()` function of jQuery. And after that I am adding the string to the textarea.

But my HTML (XHTML 1.0 specifically) is an old file to which I want to adapt to. Now this page has many JS functions like the following bounded to certain events like `onclick` and `onchange`, and this is what causes the value to be repeated in the textarea.

So if the data fetched is `string` then after all these submissions make it `string string` to be displayed in the form element.

```
function() {
    document.forms[0].action="MyServlet";
    document.forms[0].method="POST";
    document.forms[0].submit();

};
```

Is there any way I can make the AJAX to run this only once when the page is loaded? Here is what I am currently using,

```
(function() {


       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetNarrative",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { datum : "<%=id %>" },
            success: function(data) {

                 var text_area = $("#narrative");
                 text_area.val(text_area.val() + data);


            }
        });



})();
```

Comment: What is your question? It seems like your code will work just fine.

Comment: document ready handler !== self-invoking function.

Comment: I want the page only on first load to be AJAXed. Subsequent reloads should not send the request to the server.

Comment: So, why not remove the onchange & onclick specific handlers???

Comment: @A.Wolff I will remove it eventually. Just wanted to know if there is some solution in this case. (PS How would one migrate old HTML JS to new markup and JS?)